# Lua setting __index in metatable

Tags: object, lua

I try to do basic inheritance in Lua and I don't quite understand why the following doesn't index the table `mt.prototype` in my call to `print()`.

```
local x = {}

mt = {}

mt.prototype = {
  value = 5,
}

mt = {
  __index = function (table, key)
    return mt.prototype[key]
  end,
}

setmetatable(x, mt)

print(x.value)
```

It says that `mt.prototype` doesn't exist, however I don't understand why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're overwriting `mt`, on line 9, when you reassign to it. This destroys the `prototype` field.

Don't complicate things, if it's your first try with this stuff. Your `__index` function would do the same thing that letting `__index = tbl` would handle.

```
local main_table = {}

local proto_table = {
    value = 5
}

setmetatable(main_table, { __index = proto_table })

print(main_table.value)
```

If you want the slightly more complicated setup, study this:

```
local main_table = {}

local meta_table = {
    prototype = {
        value = 5
    }
}

meta_table.__index = meta_table.prototype

setmetatable(main_table, meta_table)

print(main_table.value)
```

Note that the LHS of assignment is not fully quantified during RHS evaluation, that's why the `__index` must be set on a separate line.